# Erro ao executar react-native run-android

Tags: react-native

Boa dia a todos.
Estou fazendo um curso de **React-Native** e já estou na 10ª aula. Estou rodando o projeto do curso via Depuração USB no celular.
Até então, tudo rodava funcionava direitinho mas quando atualizei a pasta SRC da 11ª aula, o **react-native run-android** passou a apresentar uns erros e não rodava mais no celular.
Então, voltei com os arquivos da 10ª aula (que funcionava bem) mas agora aparecem os erros que mostro abaixo, e não roda mais.
Como sou iniciante, não faço a menor idéia do que pode estar causando isso.
Poderiam me ajudar ? Obrigado desde já.

Seguem as linhas de erro:

```
C:\Temp\____Cursos\Samurai\Aula Smart Money\smartMoney2>npx react-native run-android
```

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1192 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
133 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 129 up-to-date
C:\Temp____Cursos\Samurai\Aula Smart Money\smartMoney2\android\app\src\main\java\com\smartmoney\MainApplication.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
^
symbol: variable BuildConfig
Note: C:\Temp____Cursos\Samurai\Aula Smart Money\smartMoney2\android\app\src\debug\java\com\smartmoney2\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Temp____Cursos\Samurai\Aula Smart Money\smartMoney2\android\app\src\main\java\com\smartmoney\MainApplication.java:22: error: cannot find symbol

C:\Temp____Cursos\Samurai\Aula Smart Money\smartMoney2>

Comment: Você instalou alguma dependência nova antes de começar a ocorrer esse erro? Se sim, qual?

Comment: Bom dia. Não instalei nada, até porque a aula não mencionava nada sobre alguma nova dependência.

Comment: Executa um `cd android`, `./gradlew clean`, `cd ..` e tenta rodar o projeto novamente. Às vezes isso resolve.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mas não adiantou. Acho que vou criar outro projeto do ZERO, colocar a 10ª aula que estava funcionando e instalar cada dependência aos poucos.